# How do I connect azure sql database to function app in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am trying to connect sql database to function app on azure.
I tried using "storage_connection_string" key in terraform.It is still not working.
Could someone please help on the issue

Comment: Please show your Terraform code.

Comment: Below is the piece of tf script which has storage_connection_string.

resource "azurerm_function_app" "function" {
 name = "azfunc"
 location = "westeurope"
 resource_group_name = "servicenow-rg"
 app_service_plan_id = "***/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/appservice"
 storage_connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string}"
 "version" = "~2"
  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "node|latest"
  }

app_settings {
 "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "python"
# "FUNCTION_APP_EDIT_MODE" = "readonly"
 "https_only" = true
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Function App deployed into Azure that's also using Azure SQL as well as a storage container. This is how it works for me. My terraform configuration is module-based so my modules for the database and storage accounts are separate, and they pass the required connection strings to my function app module:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "functions" {
  name                      = "fcn-${var.environment}
  resource_group_name       = "${var.resource_group}"
  location                  = "${var.resource_location}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${var.appservice_id}"
  storage_connection_string = "${var.storage_prim_conn_string}"

  https_only = true

  connection_string {
    name  = "SqlAzureDbConnectionString"
    type  = "SQLAzure"
    value = "${var.fcn_connection_string}"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "${var.environment}"
}
```

Just remember to check you have the module outputs as well as the variables in place.

Hope that helps.